# Combox's Textbox accepts value of selectedValuepath after tab or leaving comboBox it diplay seletedValue in combox's textBox

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding, combobox, wpf-controls

I want in application that my combobox accepts selectedvaluepath property's value and after tabbing or leaving from combobox it displays selectedValue in combobox's textbox. And also it  accepts bindded itemsource value  as in normal case.
 for example

i have comboBox binded to list as "List 1" and  in list one i have one fName and lname property . Now when user enter in to combobBox then it display fname but can search through fname but also when user enter lname then it collect fname property according to entered lanme and display fname into comboBox's textbox ...

can any one give me solution to do this with righ way......

list 1
fname  ,  Lname

aaa    ,  123,

bbb    ,  456,

ccc    ,  789,

ddd    ,  147,

eee    ,  258,

in cobobox display fname.
but if combox text enter '123' then also select 'aaa'.
when select combobox value.

Comment: i have tried to enter lname into combobox and i want that it dispaly fname but from my side its not working.. i think u may get now what i want...@ Miklós Balogh

Comment: i have bind fname and lname list to ItemsSource.in combobox display only lname.combobox selectitem by EnterText of Lname or FName imcombobox text.